# Access denied 403 phpmyadmin in xampp

Tags: permissions, apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

**I relaunch this issue:**

I can't make xampp access to phpmyadmin. I did all the configurations required yet the access is always denied.

**here is my htppd-xampp.conf file**

```
#<IfDefine PHP4>
#LoadModule php4_module        modules/libphp4.so
#</IfDefine>
#<IfDefine PHP7>
#LoadModule php7_module        modules/libphp7.so
#</IfDefine>

# We will enable it by default
#<IfDefine PHP>
   LoadModule php7_module        modules/libphp7.so
#</IfDefine>

LoadModule perl_module        modules/mod_perl.so

Alias /phpmyadmin "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin"

# since XAMPP 1.4.3
<Directory "/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin">
   AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
   Require all granted
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>

# since LAMPP 1.0RC1
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4

XBitHack on

# since 0.9.8 we've mod_perl
<IfModule mod_perl.c>
        AddHandler perl-script .pl
    PerlHandler ModPerl::PerlRunPrefork
    PerlOptions +ParseHeaders
        PerlSendHeader On
</IfModule>

# demo for mod_perl responsehandler
#PerlModule Apache::CurrentTime
#<Location /time>
#      SetHandler modperl
#      PerlResponseHandler Apache::CurrentTime
#</Location>

# AcceptMutex sysvsem is default but on some systems we need this
# thanks to jeff ort for this hint
#AcceptMutex flock
#LockFile /opt/lampp/logs/accept.lock

# this makes mod_dbd happy - oswald, 02aug06
# mod_dbd doesn't work in Apache 2.2.3: getting always heaps of "glibc detected *** corrupted double-linked list" on shutdown - oswald, 10sep06
#DBDriver sqlite3

# New XAMPP security concept
#
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

I don't know what I'm missing or doing wrong. I added the bloc LocationMatch cause it didn't exist at the beginning yet nothing changes. I hope I get some help it has been 1 day trying to make this work but it was vain.

Best

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin directory and files and directories inside it? Who's the owner and who can read from it?

Comment: I checked from filezilla: The permissions are 755 for folder and 644 for files and the owner is root from the command ls -l /phpmyadmin

Comment: still no answer